# OLAP Cube deployment issues

Tags: sql, connection, ssas, olap, cube

I'm really new to this, so I am probably making a simple mistake.

I need to make an OLAP cube using a remote database.
After I set up the dimensions and measures and create the cube, I can not get the cube to launch to the local server. 
I keep getting the error,
"The project could not be deployed to the 'localhost' server because of the following connectivity problems :  A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.  To verify or update the name of the target server, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, select Project Properties, click on the Deployment tab, and then enter the name of the server."

However, the local SQL server is running(from as far as I can tell), and I have no idea on how to go about fixing this. I've tried replacing "localhost" with "." and the IP, but that hasn't worked either.

Here's the guide I was following:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1532/build-a-cube-from-an-existing-data-source-using-sql-server-analysis-services/

Maybe the SQL Server isn't really running? How can I check? 
Or am I skipping over something important when I try to process the cube?

Answer (score 8):

you need to deploy the cube to a SSAS instance. See here I have the SQL Server instance and the SSAS instance (check the icon to see the difference):

[image]

you can check if you have it running on the services:

[image]

if you dont have it, yo ucan install from the sql server installation CD

Comment: I can't find the option to add SSAS in the 2014 setup process

Answer (score 8):

You need to change the target Server name as the remote sql server name or ip.

In BIDS right click on your project solution and select properties window. There you can give the      server name as given below figure.

[image]

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 7):

OLAP cubes will not deploy to a SQL server instance. They must be deployed to an Analysis Services instance. It will be listed as 'SQL Server Analysis Services' in your service list.

Answer (score 1):

This is what solved it for me:

1. Copy the connection from the MSSQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

2. Project > Properties > Deployment > Paste:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"localhost" refers to the machine you are running the Business Intelligence Studio from.

You say you want to deploy to a remote server, so replace localhost with the server name or the ip address (e.g. "74.125.237.146")

Answer (score 0):

to deploy a cube AS you need an SQL instance as source, and an SSAS instance as destination.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while following that tutorial.  I solved it by:

- Double Clicking the Project Data Source
- In the Impersonation Information Tab, I entered the credentials for the Windows user instead of using the service account.

Make sure you have the proper Server\Instance name instead of local host in the project deployment server.

Comment: I do not think it has to do with the data source because it cannot connect to the deployment (destination or the project) server. By the way the data source connection could be tested independently by clicking on it and selecting the Edit button in the "general" tab.

Answer (score 0):

One more reason can be Express version of SQL Server. Only standard version has Analysis Service.

Answer (score 0):

In *Microsoft SQL server* go to registered servers and click on:

> Analysis services icon -> open local server groups

Click right on your username for the server and

> service control -> start

It will work ;)